# How to create one hot vectors to find similarity of texts after gensim doc2bow implementation?

Tags: nlp, gensim, cosine-similarity, one-hot-encoding

I have two lists (say  list A and list B) of texts. I want to find most similar texts in list B for each text in list A.
This I want to do using bag of words and later cosine similarity.

I created a dictionary using gensim

```
tokensA = [preprocess_string(''.join(doc),CUSTOM_FILTERS) for doc in 
listA]
tokensB = [preprocess_string(''.join(doc),CUSTOM_FILTERS) for doc in 
listB]
# Create dictionary
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokensA)
```

Then I obtained the occurences of words for each text in list B,

```
mycorpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc, allow_update=True) for doc in tokensB]

[[(9, 1), (25, 1), (611, 1), (627, 1), (1917, 1), (1918, 1)],
[(9, 1), (25, 1), (627, 1), (1918, 1), (1919, 1), (1920, 1)],...
```

How can I convert this to vectors so that I can do a cosine_similarity?

Comment: How getting the one-hot vector will help you get the similarity?

Comment: I was thinking to use cosine_similarity(vecA,vecB) similar to sklearn countvectorizer/tfidfvectorizer.

Comment: vec_a = matrix.fit_transform(tokensa).toarray()
vec_b = matrix.transform(tokensb).toarray() cosine_similarity(vec_a,vec_b)